# javascript get value of html radio button input selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a simple form like this :

```
<form id="formSearch">
<label><input type="radio" name="number" value="1">singular</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="number" value="2">plural</label><br><br>
<INPUT type="Submit" Value="Show" name="show" ></INPUT>
</form>
```

I want to get the "radio-value" of the selected button with javascript :

```
var account = document.getElementsByName("number").value;
```

do not give the correct response. if I give a trap :

```
alert(account);
```

the result is : undefined. 
I do not know where the harm, is there who is willing to help me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript:

```
document.querySelector('[name=number]:checked').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

In jquery, you can use the checked attribute selector for that

```
$("[name='number']:checked").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function test() {
  
  var checkedRadioBtnList=new Array();
  
  var account = document.getElementsByName("number");
  
  for(i=0; i<account.length;i++){  
    if(account[i].checked){      
      checkedRadioBtnList.push({value:account[i].value});
    }    
  }
  
  console.log(checkedRadioBtnList);
}
```

```html
<form id="formSearch">
<label><input type="radio" name="number" value="1">singular</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="number" value="2">plural</label><br><br>
<INPUT type="Submit" Value="Show" name="show" onclick="test()" ></INPUT>
</form>
```

*`getElementsByName` will return an array.*

**EDIT**

I had simply answer the question, how to get checked value using `javascript`.

There are lots of option to store values as per application. I have improve my answer to store `checked` radio button values in an `Array` using `JSON Object`.

Comment: But how do you know which element is selected? Simply accessing the first radio is not a solution.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan check my updated answer.

Comment: alerts false if i choose plural.

Comment: @Jitendra Tiwari : This way right if there are only two choices ( singular and plural ), what if there are more than two options ?

Comment: @Jai, @agus I have update my answer. please check my comment on `EDIT` part.